# Django: I dont know want is the wrong with my code

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So I was trying to add an imagefield in my model using the UserModel, so I made this models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField()

def user_avatar(self):
    return self.profileimage.avatar

User.add_to_class('user_avatar', user_avatar)
```

And I made an admin to see the imagefield in the users,
admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Register your models here.

UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('user_avatar',)}),
```

I dont kno what is wrong with my code, when I open a user to see the image field and [image: this happened], does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin `fields` and `fieldsets` expects you to list actual columns in the database. `user_avatar` is a function you've written so you can't list it as a field on the `User` model because it doesn't exist in that table.

Make a more generic model for all types of user information, not just an image, like this;

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField()
```

Then you can access the avatar with `request.user.profile.avatar` or in your admin register your `Profile` model as an inline to the `User`;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from myapp.accounts.models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False

class MyUserAdmin(admin.UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline]

# unregister old user admin
admin.site.unregister(User)

# register new user admin that includes a UserProfile
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```